# Color space term? (RGB / I values)

Tags: color, color-theory, rgb

I found ascii document with 3d data. It was said:

> ascii text file of point cloud with **RGB / I values**

Here you can see part of document:

- 0.805, 10.301, -1.860, **165, 66, 65, 66**
- 0.806, 10.311, -1.859, **157, 66, 65, 74**
- 0.820, 10.298, -1.859, **209, 66, 65, 74**

I did not found help on this format and cannot understand what is **I values**. Is there such a term "RGB / I values" in color theory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 3D applications, I (for "Intensity") is used to indicate the brightness of a light source whose color is defined using R. G and B values that are usually normalized (fit into range of 0 to 1). It's not really a part of color theory; it's part of how lights are defined in a 3D environment so that things like fall-off, specular reflections, etc., can be calculated. That may be what you have in this case, although it's hard to tell without a bit more context.